# Disable/Enable Taskmanager with VBS

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, taskmanager

```
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "calc" ,,true   
msgbox "Calc finished"
WSHShell.Run "userinit.exe"
```

I need Taskmanager disabled from the beginning of the script until userinit.exe gets executed. I'm using Win 7 and i don't know how to do it. (I searched a lot but nothing worked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a registry value, using the registry editor *cmdline* equivalent: *reg.exe*. Here's an example:

```bat
WSHShell.Run("Reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f", 0, 1)
```

In order to enable it, reset the same registry value: `/d 0`.

Details can be found in [[TweakAndTrick]: Enable Task Manager disabled by Administrator or Virus in Windows](https://www.tweakandtrick.com/2011/07/enable-task-manager-windows-virus.html).

Note that depending on your user, some registry key permissions adjustments might be necessary.

Comment: Well that actualy worked. But now, everytime i start the script it asks for administrator rights. How can i prevent that?.

Comment: Is that the pop-up dialog that you need to click _Run as Administrator_ button? What user are you logged on as? What user are you trying to run the script as? Is it the behavior from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) or [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/)? There could be the possibility of disabling _UAC_ or automatically elevating the privileges but only on System level.

Comment: Hmm as a workaround, what if you create a shortcut to the bat file and from its properties (in the _Advanced_ tab) check _Run as administrator_?